# Error with algorithm package occurred when using standalone subfile

Tags: algorithms, standalone, algorithmic, subfiles

I am trying to create a standalone subfile in which I want to add some algorithms.

The document is compiled right when I am using the  `\documentclass[9pt]{article}` in the preamble. But the following error occurred when I change it into

```
\documentclass[float=false, crop=false]{standalone}
\usepackage[subpreambles=true]{standalone}`
```

The error output:

```
ERROR: Extra }, or forgotten \endgroup.
--- TeX said ---
\@endfloatbox ...pagefalse \outer@nobreak \egroup                                                          \color@endbox 
l.28 \end{algorithm}

--- HELP ---
From the .log file...

I've deleted a group-closing symbol because it seems to be
spurious, as in `$x}$'. But perhaps the } is legitimate and
you forgot something else, as in `\hbox{$x}'. In such cases
the way to recover is to insert both the forgotten and the
deleted material, e.g., by typing `I$}'.
```

Whole code:

```
%\documentclass[float=false, crop=false]{standalone}
%\usepackage[subpreambles=true]{standalone}

\documentclass[9pt]{article} 
\usepackage{import}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{siunitx}

\usepackage{algorithm}
\usepackage[noend]{algpseudocode}
\begin{document}

\begin{center}
\begin{algorithm}{}
    \caption{Euclid’s algorithm}
    \label{euclid}
    \begin{algorithmic}[1] % The number tells where the line numbering should start
        \Procedure{Euclid}{$a,b$} \Comment{The g.c.d. of a and b}
            \State $r\gets a \bmod b$
            \While{$r\not=0$} \Comment{We have the answer if r is 0}
                \State $a \gets b$
                \State $b \gets r$
                \State $r \gets a \bmod b$
            \EndWhile\label{euclidendwhile}
            \State \textbf{return} $b$\Comment{The gcd is b}
        \EndProcedure
    \end{algorithmic}
\end{algorithm}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

**Edit**

Problem solved by replacing the floating boolean value in documentclass `\documentclass[float=true, crop=false]{standalone}` I am not sure why.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem solved by replacing the floating boolean value in documentclass `\documentclass[float=true, crop=false]{standalone}`

Answer (score 1):

Since standalone does not have a predefined width, normal text breaking doesn't apply.  You will need to put everything inside a minipage or use the varwidth package.  Other things are undefined or just not a good idea in standalone.

```
\documentclass[varwidth]{standalone}
\usepackage[noend]{algpseudocode}
\begin{document}
    \begin{algorithmic}[1] % The number tells where the line numbering should start
        \Procedure{Euclid}{$a,b$} \Comment{The g.c.d. of a and b}
            \State $r\gets a \bmod b$
            \While{$r\not=0$} \Comment{We have the answer if r is 0}
                \State $a \gets b$
                \State $b \gets r$
                \State $r \gets a \bmod b$
            \EndWhile%\label{euclidendwhile}% won't work
            \State \textbf{return} $b$\Comment{The gcd is b}
        \EndProcedure
    \end{algorithmic}
\end{document}
```

---

And this is how you should use it in a document.  BTW, don't put floats inside a center environment.

```
\documentclass[9pt]{article} 
\usepackage{import}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{siunitx}

\usepackage{algorithm}
%\usepackage[noend]{algpseudocode}% not needed
\usepackage{graphicx}
\begin{document}

\begin{algorithm}
    \caption{Euclid’s algorithm}
    \label{euclid}
    \includegraphics{test5}% insert your filensmae here
\end{algorithm}
\end{document}
```

[image: demo]